# Нужно регулярным выражением найти всё, что внутри кавычек, но исключая сами кавычки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть, например, текст:

> Lorem ipsum "dolor sit amet", consectetur "adipisicing" elit, sed do eiusmod
> tempor incididunt ut labore et "dolore magna aliqua".

Нужно регулярным выражением найти всё, что внутри `""`.

РВ: `"(.*?)"` находит вместе с `"`. Как исключить `"` из поиска?

Comment: Берите первую группу захвата, а не нулевую из результата.

Comment: Можно более развернуто, пожалуйста

Comment: Язык какой используете?

Comment: Посмотрите в Match Information: https://regex101.com/r/JKDHq9/1

Comment: Укажите язык / библиотеку регулярных выражений. Ваше выражение уже составлено так, как надо (конечно, `"([^"]*)"` / `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` лучше, но всё равно ваше уже рабочее).

Comment: Язык php. Подскажите как РВ сказать "НЕ")

Comment: @sv458 http://ideone.com/h63HjP - не надо НЕ, просто `$m[1]`

Comment: Если язык поддерживает предпросмотр назад и вперёд, то можно воспользоваться ими. Однако, там будет жесть, поскольку понадобится проверять чётность числа кавычек. Лучше просто брать первую группу, как уже подсказали.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте это регулярное выражение:

```
"([^"]+)"
```

Нужные вам значения будут в переменной $1.

> Подскажите как РВ сказать "НЕ")

Надо заключить нужный символ (или класс символов) в квадратные скобки и поставить перед ним `^`.

Чтобы исключить не символ/класс, а подстроку (или паттерн), надо использовать *негативный опережающий поиск.*

Comment: [Ваше регулярное выражение содержит ошибку](https://regex101.com/r/cDnXRk/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew исправил опечатку, теперь все ok

Comment: Вы же видите, что не в регулярке вообще дело. То выражение, что есть в вопросе, уже рабочее. К тому же, в `\"([^\"]+)\"` нет `$2`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew поправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $str = 'Lorem ipsum "dolor sit amet", consectetur "adipisicing" elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et "dolore magna aliqua".';
  $pattern = '"(.*?)"';
  preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
?>
```

в $matches[1] результаты без кавычек.
@Visman - спасибо.

Comment: А не я ли вам код показал?

Comment: Пардонте) И Вам @WiktorStribiżew спасибо. regexp посмотрел, а Ваша ссылка осталась незамеченной